# similar ClientChatReceivedEvent for Client only sendMessage (Minecraft Forge Modding)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I just started with java and minecraft modding. I want to implement a very simple task but unfortunately I do not know the right event for it.
Messages sent via

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.sendChatMessage(message);
```

from the client to the server I can use:

```
public void onChat(ClientChatReceivedEvent event)
```

to read it back in.
However, there are now also messages that are sent via

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.sendMessage(m)
```

only direct to the client. Is there also a possibility to read these messages? Another mod writes these "client only" messages that I want to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

You can. You have to read output packet that contains sent messages like that :

```java
@Inject(method = "sendPacket(Lnet/minecraft/network/Packet;)V", at = @At("HEAD"), cancellable = true)
private void onSendPacket(Packet<?> packet, CallbackInfo callbackInfo) {
   // System.out.println("Packet Sent: " + packet.toString());
   // here you can get the packet type, then if it's chat's you can get content
   // you can cancel it with: callbackInfo.cancel();
}
```

[Source](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/74173-on-packet-sendrecieve-events/?do=findComment&comment=357895)